# jQuery .ajax submit not working in IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

On any of my pages such as [this one](http://www.ninjatrader.com/about.php) when you click the "Have a Question" button left column a form comes up through jQuery Tools overlay. You fill out the form, it submits to a PHP script (a local one) and if it validates and submits you get either a thank you or error message depending on what the response is from the server. Works great in FF, safari and Opera, but not in IE or Chrome. IE and Chrome just go and print the return message the .ajax looks for on a blank page with the script URL. I must have something incorrect as even my cross domain cURL ajax scripting works but not this! Here is the code

```
$(document).click(function() {
        $.validator.methods.equal = function(value, element, param) {
        return value == param;
    };
    var validator = $("#request").bind("invalid-form.validate", function() {
            $("#summary").html("Your form contains " + validator.numberOfInvalids() + " error(s), please fix.");
        }).validate({
            //debug: true,
            errorElement: "em",
            errorContainer: $("#summary"),
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo( element.parent("li"));
            },
            success: function(label) {
                label.text("ok!").addClass("success");
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $("#processing").show();
            var dataString = $(form).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                type: $("#request").attr('method'),
                url: form.action,
                data: dataString,
                clearForm: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data=="SuccessMail Sent") {
                        $("#formWrap, #supportHdln").hide();
                            $("#thankYou").html('<h2><span>Thank You</span> We have received your request.</h2><p>A Customer Service Representative from NinjaTrader will contact you shortly.</p>').fadeIn("slow");
                        } else {
                            $("#formWrap, #supportHdln").hide();
                            $("#error").html('<h2><span>Uh Oh</span> We are unable to process your request.</h2><p>Please make sure all fields were filled out correctly. If you are still having trouble, please <a href=\"mailto:support@ninjatrader.com?subject=Support Email\">email us</a></p>').fadeIn("slow");
                    }
                    }
                });
            return false;

           },
            rules: {
                    hs_customer_firstname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                    hs_customer_lastname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                    hs_customer_email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                    confirmEmail: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    equalTo: "#hs_customer_email"
                },
                    hs_customer_phone: {
                    required: false,
                    digits: true
                },
                    hs_category: {
                    required: true      
                },
                    hs_customLargeTextField: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20
                },
                    math: {
                    required: true,
                    equal: <?php echo $randomNumTotal; ?>   
                }
            },

            messages: {
                hs_customer_firstname: {
                    required: "Please Enter Your First Name",
                    minlength: "Your First Name Must be at Least 2 Characters"
                },
                hs_customer_lastname: {
                    required: "Please Enter Your Last Name",
                    minlength: "Your Last Name Must be at Leaset 2 Characters"
                },
                hs_customer_email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email address",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                },
                confirmEmail: {
                    required: "Please Confirm Your Email Address",
                    email: "Please Enter a Valid Email Address",
                    equalTo: "Please Enter the Same Email Address as Above"
                },
                hs_customer_phone: {
                    digits: "Numbers only"
                },

                hs_category:  {
                    required: "Please Select a Category"
                },
                hs_customLargeTextField: {
                    required: "Please Leave a Comment",
                    minlength: "Your comment must be at least 20 characters"
                },
                math: {
                    required: "Please Solve the Problem",
                    equal: "Please Solve the Problem Correctly"
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

and here's the tiny PHP script that runs it

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST['hs_customer_firstname']) || empty($_POST['hs_customer_lastname']) ||
empty($_POST['hs_customer_email']) || empty($_POST['hs_category']) ||
empty($_POST['hs_customLargeTextField']) || empty($_POST['math'])) {
echo ('Success');
}

$headers = 'From: webmaster@ninjatrader.com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: webmaster@ninjatrader.com' . "\r\n" .

$firstname = $_POST['hs_customer_firstname'] ;
//more like this

mail( "email@domain.com", "Support Request",
//$_POST fields 
"From: $email");
if(mail($firstname, $lastname, $email, $category, $inquiry)) {
echo ('Mail Sent');
} else {
echo ('Error: Mail failed');
}

?>
```

Comment: You look at the Network tab in the console to see your request?

Comment: yes, and it displays the expected message! thats what sucks.

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design: Are you making sure to cancel the default behavior of the form before you submit it via AJAX? I've seen weird behavior when I forget to do event.preventDefault() (jQuery).  I can't tell if this is happening b/c I don't see where you're wiring up the submit event to the form.

Comment: @Andrew yes i have a return false after the submitHandler. I dont know why this would work on safari and not chrome? aren't they both webkit? I really appreciate any help/advice you can give.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem next time. No one likes reading through a hundred lines of code

Comment: Actually Pablo, and I know it wasn't your intention to help, but you did. I ended up reconstructing it all with the ajax call on the parent page, not the page thats loaded in the shadowbox and it works. the only issue is the randomnumber captcha I was using doesn't work.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Actually, I **did** try to help you. The problem didn't seem really strange/hard but you didn't get any answer.The thing is that people usually don't have time to read through a lot of pages of code. Keeping your questions succinct will get you better and more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with the random number validation, IE and Chrome didn't like the  in the js code. Once I got rid of that, and removed the validation from the form page being brought in with the overlay, added it to the parent page as a separate JS file it worked. Not sure why the random num total doesn't work though. When I added the PHP function to the parent page, it didn't trigger a JS error in the validation, but the numbers didn't validate when you added them correctly. Oh well, win some lose some.